# Detecting if a route is a resource or route

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-router

As the titles says, im looking for a way to detect if the route that im using is a resource or just a route. For those of you confused im speaking about the router structure of the application. For example 'person' is my resource and it has the routes 'edit', 'list' and 'view'... i need to be able to know from the routes standpoint if its a normal route, or a resource.

**EDIT:** I actually went ahead and just created a controller for each of my **resources** and assigned it a property **isResource: true**. This will suffice for what im doing but if anyone has a way to detect this in the routes **willTransition** or **didTransition** that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From looking at [the source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/5fe2d63a7dab0484cad9e729886ac71b4c05f1fd/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/dsl.js), I don’t think it’s possible. The relevant lines from the definition of the `resource` method:

```
options.resetNamespace = true;
this.route(name, options, callback);
```

I can’t see anywhere in `route` that the `resource` origin of a route declaration is preserved in the generated route.

Comment: Thanks for your input Buck, i was thinking the same thing.